# How to use Selenium Java to publish / retrieve AWS SQS Message

Tags: selenium-webdriver, amazon-sqs

I am starting to use AWS SQS. As a quality engineer, my testing of this is going to need to be automated. Right now I've been using Selenium Java and Cypress. I've been trying to find information on how to push messages to the queue and potentially read the messages from the queue, but I'm not really finding any good documentation on it.

Any help would be appreciated.

AWS Documentation
Selenium Documentation
Good Searching